# jsf comandLink added with jquery .append() doesn't work

Tags: jquery, jsf

i've added some code with jquery `.append()`

```
$('#div').append('<div id="windiv">'+
            '<h:commandLink id="cmdbtn">'+
            '<div id="reducebtndiv" class="btn"></div>'+
        '<f:ajax event="click" execute="@form"'+
                'listener="#{screenShotBean.takeScreenshot}" ></f:ajax>'+
                    '</h:commandLink>');
```

but the commandLink doesn't work.
so the question is, is there a way to make it work ? i also appreciate to know some theory about this. :)

Answer (score 2):

The `commandLink` doesn't work because you are adding it using JavaScript, which is run by the client (the browser).

JSF views (made of JSF components) need to be processed on the server side, when they are rendered they output proper HTML elements that can be processed by your browser. JSF Components are not standard HTML elements and thus they are not recognized by the browsers.

it's difficult to guess what you want to achieve but, if you want to add some JSF components dynamically, then you'll need to trigger an AJAX request against the server and re-render the part of your view where those components need to be inserted (as HTML, of course).

Comment: The code generated by JSF for the commandLink and the f:ajax is the following : <a id="form:cmdbtn" href="#" onclick="mojarra.ab(this,event,'click','@form',0);return false">
  <div id="reducebtndiv" class="btn"></div></a>  , i added both mojarra.js and jsf.js which is requiered by it and put this code directly in a .xhml file but it doesn't work neither..

Comment: that sounds more like a hack than a solution, even if it worked I would never try that, if Mojarra implementation changes someday in the future your code will stop working. Why don't we start from the beginning? what exactly do you want to achieve? I'm sure you can do it in a JSF fashion

Comment: i don't understand why it seems as a hack as it s an open source framework ! what i want is to add code with js which can hit a managed bean method (an AjaxBehaviorEvent listener handler) which i coudn't do with the JSF javascript API as i can't set a "listener" with it..and also have the possibility to add that code with the jquery .append().But whatever , i know that i can include some code by another way. Thank u anyway :)

Comment: it's a hack because you were trashing your application with implementation specific stuff from Mojarra's guts, instead of relying on its standard usage. Besides "having the possibility of adding _that code_ with `jquery.append()`" is not the best approach to do it, you could however make a request to the server and then output its results in your view. As usual, there are many ways of achieving the same, some a better ones than the others, some are simply wrong.